# Very strange behaivour. Why are my radio buttons not checking when I click them?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, radio-button

[image]

Hi guys, any idea why when I click my radio buttons they do not work? I have used radio buttons on other components and they work fine. I'm using Vue.

The radio buttons are the same name, and if I add `checked` to them, they do indeed check. However even when one is checked, it will not allow me to click and check another.

template:

```
`<template >
  <div class="desktop-new-user">
    <div id="MyFirstSlideshow">
      <div class="eg-slideshow">
        <transition name="fade">
          <slide>
            <div class="desktop-new-user__text-wrapper">
              <h1>Starting your career has never been so easy.</h1>
              <p>All graduate and intern opportunities are now in one place</p>
              <div class="desktop-new-user__input-wrapper">
                <div class="desktop-new-user__input-wrapper__radio-wrapper">
                  <div class="desktop-new-user__input-wrapper__radio-wrapper__option-1">
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      name="new-user-job-type"
                      value="graduate"
                      class="desktop-new-user__input-wrapper__radio-wrapper__radio-input"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="desktop-new-user__input-wrapper__radio-wrapper__option-2">
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      name="new-user-job-type"
                      value="intern"
                      class="desktop-new-user__input-wrapper__radio-wrapper__radio-input"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="desktop-new-user__input-wrapper__input-text"
                  placeholder="What are you interested in?"
                />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="desktop-new-user__input-wrapper__input-text"
                  placeholder="Where would you like to work?"
                />
                <button class="desktop-new-user__input-wrapper__btn-search">
                  <p>Search</p>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="desktop-new-user__img-wrapper">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/>" alt />
            </div>
          </slide>
        </transition>

        <transition name="fade">
          <slide enter="bounceInRight" leave="fadeOut">
            <div class="desktop-new-user__text-wrapper">
              <h1>Create a profile to get better career suggestions</h1>
              <p>All graduate and intern opportunities are now in one place</p>
            </div>
            <div class="desktop-new-user__img-wrapper">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/>" alt />
            </div>
          </slide>
        </transition>
        <transition name="fade">
          <slide enter="fadeIn">
            <div class="desktop-new-user__text-wrapper">
              <h1>Coming soon to STU!</h1>
              <p>All graduate and intern opportunities are now in one place</p>
            </div>
            <div class="desktop-new-user__img-wrapper">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/>" alt />
            </div>
          </slide>
        </transition>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>`
```

script:

```
<script>
    import { Slideshow } from "eagle.js";
    export default {
      name: "DesktopNewUser",
      mixins: [Slideshow],
      methods: {
        updateJobSelector: function() {
          const option1left = this.$refs.option1.getBoundingClientRect().left;
          const option2left = this.$refs.option2.getBoundingClientRect().left;
          if (this.jobType === "graduate") {
            this.$refs.jobTypeSelector.style.left = "0";
            this.$refs.pGraduate.style.color = "#FFFFFFff";
            this.$refs.pIntern.classList.add("p-blue");
          } else if (this.jobType === "intern") {
            this.$refs.jobTypeSelector.style.left = "50%";
            this.$refs.pIntern.classList.remove("p-blue");
            this.$refs.pIntern.style.color = "#FFFFFFff";
            this.$refs.pGraduate.style.color = "#6734e9";
          }
        }
      },
      data: function() {
        return {
          jobType: "graduate"
        };
      }
    };
    </script>
```

styling:

```
<style lang="scss">
@import "../../../styles/_variables.scss";
.desktop-new-user {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  position: relative;
  &__text-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    & h1 {
      width: 60%;
    }

    & p {
      font-size: 2rem;
      color: $colour-grey-light;
    }
  }
  &__input-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    &__input-text {
      &::placeholder {
        font-size: 2rem;
      }
      height: 6rem;
      width: 30%;
      border-radius: 2.5rem;
      padding-left: 2rem;
      font-size: 2rem;
      border: 0.1rem solid $colour1;
      transition: all 0.5s;
      margin-bottom: 2rem;

      &:focus {
        border: 0.1rem solid $colour2;
      }
    }
    &__radio-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      height: 10rem;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 30%;
    }
    &__btn-search {
      @include gradientbg;
      width: 15rem;
      height: 6rem;
      font-size: 2rem;
      border-radius: 2.5rem;
      padding: 1rem 2rem;
      transition: all 0.2s;
      border: none;
      color: $colour4;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: solid 0.1rem transparent;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      &:before {
        content: "";
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        border-radius: 2rem;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
      }
      &:hover::before {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
      &:hover {
        color: $colour1;
        border: solid 0.1rem $colour1;
      }
      &:hover p {
        color: $colour1;
      }
      & p {
        text-align: center;
        color: $colour4;
        font-size: 2rem;
        position: relative;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
        z-index: 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
#MyFirstSlideshow {
  .eg-slideshow {
    .eg-slide {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;

      .eg-slide-content {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        text-align: left !important;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        max-width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
    }
  }
}
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-out;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `v-model="jobType"` on each of the `<input>` elements? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio

Comment: @skirtle yes there should be, i deleted the v-models to test if would work and it doesn't. If the job type is "graduate" the first radio will be checked, if it's "intern" the second one will be checked. 
However clicking them still doesn't work